# tar exclude and include inclusive

Tags: unix, tar

I am having a problem with a tar command.  When I use both the exclude and include (-X/-T) commands at the same time, I can create a tar file.  However, when I only use the exclude flags, I get the "Cannot create an empty tar" error.

This command works:

```
tar-cf directory/tarfile -C directory/tardirectory -X excludelist1.txt -X excludelist2.txt -T includelist1.txt
```

However, this errors out:

```
tar-cf directory/tarfile -C directory/tardirectory -X excludelist1.txt -X excludelist2.txt
```

If I use the -X flag, do I also need to use the -T flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `-T` you have to specify the directory or files to be archived as command line arguments:

```
tar -cf directory/tarfile -C directory/tardirectory -X excludelist1.txt -X excludelist2.txt .
```

`.` means the current directory (relative to the directory named in `-C`).